# In Ubuntu 16.04, connecting through vino only shows the top leftmost screen (High DPI screen)

Tags: vnc, ubuntu-16.04, high-dpi

When I connect to my machine with VNC under vino, I only see the top-left side quarter of the screen.

Is there a way to fix it so I can see the whole screen?

**Details**

My machine is ubuntu 16.04, my screen resolution is 3840x2160

I tried with several VNC clients (tigervnc, tightvnc, remmina), and I tried rebooting the machine several time, but nothing helped.

EDIT: 
Both (server and client) machines are high resolution

Comment: Are both machines high-resolution? It's not clear whether the details you give are about the local or remote machine, or both.

Comment: both machine are high resolution. I'll edit the question

Comment: I don't have UHD screens, but Remmina on Ubuntu 18.04 works well with HD and 3200x1800monitors, provided I choose the correct scale factor, and I had no problems on 16.04 before I upgraded. Have you tried different scales (eg full-screen `RightCtrl+LeftCtrl` and/or scaled `RightCtrl+s`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I experienced the same issue and discovered it's being caused by a scaling bug in Vino (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vino/+bug/1668309). As of April 8th 2019 this bug has yet to be fixed.

The exact bug can be reproduced like so (copied verbatim from bug report):

> STEPS:
>
> 1. On a 4K system
> 2. Do a default install of the current iso for Zesty
> 3. Make sure scalling is set to 2
> 4. Once in the user session activate desktop-sharing
> 5. Connect from another machine
>
> EXPECTED:
>
> - I expect to see the whole screen or for the screen to scroll
>     to allow access to the whole screen
>
> ACTUAL:
>
> - Top left hand quarter is the only thing visible and no changes
>     to remina make it better.

In order to prevent Vino from cropping your screen you will have to **lower the resolution to at least 1080p** *and* **reset the scaling factor to 1**. I tested this on Ubuntu 18.04 and it seems to be working well.

Comment: I have filled a bug report in upstream: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/vino/issues/9